# ASP.net MVC and Entity Framework sites sharing database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I've recently started to play around with ASP.net MVC3 and the Entity Framework. I followed tutorials (code, model and database first) and I liked alot of the automagical things happening.

BUT (always a but...), it seem to me that the whole "system" is very much constructed for someone hosting the whole thing by themselves with total control. I'm trying to understand how it can be useful to me in my hobby projects and self learning and so far I've failed.

What I'm getting at is this: I have a pretty regular web hotel, I own a couple of domains there. But I only have 1 MS SQL database. And it seems which every way I go with code, model or database first my sites/projects/tests fight eachother in that database - dropping eachothers tables.

On the web hotel I have to use a package from NuGet so that only tables are being created on model change - no database dropping allowed. But tables that not exist in one sites project are being dropped and conflicts arrise.

Am I missing something or did they really not construct the framework for people like me?

If I had a MS SQL database dedicated for each site I want to work on it would work of course but since that is an extra service it will get very expensive. And my projects are very tiny at this pont so having them share a database is no problem performance-wise.

Can anyone advice me, say what point I'm missing or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the code-first variety of EF.  Try the database-first variety and generate your model from the database, rather than vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for a very fast reply!

Comment: I have tried that but it seemed to end up with the same "fight". i created 2 test sites (veery simple ones) and they did drop eachothers tables and/or complained that the model had been changed.

Comment: @Gaaah What action did you perform to make EF drop the tables?

Comment: To ellaborate: 1 database but 2 or more MVC projects.. Even if I do database first doesnt that mean the problem I described OR that I need to have the same model with loads of classes connected to other project's tables?'

Comment: When ever I work on one of the projects and change the model.

Comment: Or when I use the sites and have them for instance add something to a table. If the table doesnt exist in db it is generated. And when site number 2 comes along it does the same and at that point drops the first projects tables.  I must be doing something very wrong :-) Otherwise this place would have been filled with this.

Comment: You only need to use the tables that you want for a particular project in any given project. Just don't add the tables you're not interested in. Try this tutorial  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489.aspx

Comment: True true true. I think I do know where I went so wrong. Thanks for your time!